# NAT to a fixed IP via load balancer?

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, load-balancing, nat, port-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network Redundancy Example](https://serverfault.com/questions/109665/network-redundancy-example)

I got a network configuration as shown in the diagram. Thing is I want do some settings so that the public can access to the server from outside of LAN. For example, when the public key in 22.22.22.22 in web browser, they will be redirect (or reroute) to the web hosted on 192.168.0.100. Is that possible?

Thanks.

[image: Network diagram]

Answer (score 0):

configure a 1 to 1 nat between the public ip to the local at  the router or at the firewall end, so that when  user who keys in 22.22.22.22 will be directed to the local ip 192.168.0.100..

**EXtra if You want  you can try this:**   Adding to this  If you are concerned with providing more security to your server from  external network  you can even configure a reverse proxy so that  You can have all the request to 22.22.22.22 forwarded  (based on the nat to the local server  say 192.168.0.75 then from here you can configure the real  redirection t your 192.168.0.100 by installing apache server and do the configuration  its just a 2 lines  of it. this will be like a double protection.

Answer (score -1):

You can use keepalived on the load balancer. (http://www.keepalived.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is that the load balancer is a router (dlink) not a physical server